# Best M.2 SSD format settings for shared Linux/Windows drive

Tags: disk, format

I have a 1TB M.2 SSD in my PC that I want to format to use as my Linux drive for a dual-boot Linux setup. When I go to format the disk, I can allocate in units of 512, 1024, 2048, 4096 and so on bytes. The default is 4096 bytes, NTFS.

Should I prefer a particular byte size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hard drive has a physical sector size. If that physical sector size is 4096 than you should format your drive with the same sector size. Generally speaking `gparted` should recognize this and format your drive in the sectorsize and alignment that your drive needs. Since several years manufacturers are using 4096 as physical sector size and emulate 512 bytes. 512 bytes was the old standard and 4096 is the new one. They went from 512 to 4096 because of the increasing capacities of the hard drives.

You could rund `fdisk -l` 
Your output could look like this:

```
fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 119,2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa4b57300
```

In this case the hard drive has 120 GB of space and a physical sector size of 512 bytes.

Comment: Thanks.  On Windows, wmic diskdrive list /format:csv is showing BytesPerSector of 512, and leaves MaxBlockSize and MinBlockSize blank.  System Summary / Storage/ Disks also gives no block size.  My disks are all SSDs, so I guess it may just ignore the block size when partitioning.

Comment: sorry i have know clue how windows handles / shows this.